# set variable value in update statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I have the following stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `vanter`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `updateItemQuantity`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateItemQuantity`(IN _quantity DOUBLE, IN _puCost DOUBLE, IN _itemState INT, IN _itemId LONG, IN _dateTime DATETIME)
BEGIN


SELECT @PUCOST := PU_COST FROM itemmanagement WHERE id=_itemId;

UPDATE itemmanagement  SET QUANTITY =QUANTITY+_quantity
WHERE id=_itemId;

INSERT INTO item_management_detail( DATE_TIME, ITEM_DETAIL_STATE, FK_ITEM, PU_COST, QUANTITY)
VALUES (_dateTime, _itemState, _itemId, @PUCOST, _quantity);    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I have two following statements that hit two time in db

```
SELECT @PUCOST := PU_COST FROM itemmanagement WHERE id=_itemId;

UPDATE itemmanagement  SET QUANTITY =QUANTITY+_quantity
WHERE id=_itemId;
```

I want to assign the value to @PUCOST in update statement, as follow , any resolution?

```
UPDATE itemmanagement  SET QUANTITY =QUANTITY+_quantity , @PUCOST := PU_COST
WHERE id=_itemId;
```

Comment: currently i got this solution for now `UPDATE itemmanagement  SET QUANTITY =QUANTITY+_quantity, PU_COST=(@PUCOST := PU_COST)
 WHERE id=_itemId;` But do not want to update PU_COST. lemme do more R&D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case`:

```
UPDATE itemmanagement 
    SET QUANTITY = (CASE WHEN (@PUCOST := PU_COST) = NULL THEN NULL -- never get here
                         ELSE QUANTITY + _quantity
                    END)
WHERE id = _itemId;
```

Comment: This is not what I need

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor . . . This appears to exactly answer your question.